# Solution to route packages of different machines to different gateways

Tags: networking, proxy, network-programming

I have the following scenario:

I have N gateways N1,...,N5 
and M machines M1,...,M5 , with N > M.

I want all machines to connect to the internet via diffent gateways.
In example :
M1 should connect through N1
M2 should connect throught N3
M3 should connect through N5
M4 should connect through N6
M5 should connect throught N7

and the rest gateways should be available.

Between the machines and the gateways should be a server that 'forwards' each machines traffic to the correct gateway. Also this servers should be able to assign a new gateway 
(from the unused ones ) to the machine that requested it.

Do you have any ideas of how to implement this idea?
I am thinking using firewall rules but maybe there is already an existing solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I want all machines to connect to the internet via diffent gateways. In example : M1 should connect through N1 M2 should connect throught N3 M3 should connect through N5 M4 should connect through N6 M5 should connect throught N7

Is there something wrong with assigning a different Vlan and subnet to each gateway, and configuring the default-route on Mx for the appropriate gateway?